# sports - title-- -- > {} third-- -- > undefined

Tags: javascript, html

- i am new to js
- Around eight hours I am trying to debug why I am getting the below empty object
- document.getElementsByClassName("sports-title") is working fine in fiddle but when I put in my code base its not working fine.
- it is returning like this so I am not able to proceed.

  codebase output
  sports - title-- -- > {}
  third-- -- > undefined

  fiddle ouput

  sports-title---->{"0":{}} third---->{}
- I am using same html structure.
- can you guys tell me what could be problem so that I can proceed.

```or-tag-here
findStringInsideDiv() {

    var sportsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("sports-title");
    var third = sportsTitle[0];
    var thirdHTML = third.innerHTML



    //str = str.split(" ")[4];
    console.log("sports-title---->" + JSON.stringify(sportsTitle));
        console.log("third---->" + JSON.stringify(third));
    console.log("thirdHTML---->" + JSON.stringify(thirdHTML));


    if ( thirdHTML === " basketball football swimming " ) {

          console.log("matching basketball---->");


      var menu = document.querySelector('.sports');
      menu.classList.add('sports-with-basketball');

      // how to add this class name directly to the first div after body.
      // but we are not rendering that div in accordion
      //is it possible

    }

    else{
    console.log("not matching");
    }

  }
```

Comment: note that your jsfiddle example has a huge syntax error: `React.render((<div>...</div>), ...)` — the HTML there needs to be in a string, or you'll get `"SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'"`

Answer (score 0):

If `document.getElementsByClassName("sports-title")` isn't returning any elements this could mean:

- Your HTML source doesn't have any elements with `class="sports-title"`, possibly because of a syntax error, spelling error, etc.. Try inspecting your web page with a browser's DOM inspector and look for the elements which you think should be in the `sports-title` class.

Or

- Your Javascript is executing before the `.sports-title` elements are actually added to the document, because scripts are (normally) executed synchronously during document parsing, as soon as the parser encounters them. **Try moving the `<script>` element to the end of the `<body>`, after all the other elements are defined.**

There may be other possible causes that I can't think of right now.

Comment: will it be problem due to componentWillMount since both the conditions which you said is perfectly done

Comment: @texirv I have no idea, since I know nothing about ReactJS

Answer (score -1):

This probably isn't the answer but I can't leave a comment so here goes:

I was messing with your jsFiddle and I noticed that if you change `JSON.stringify(object)` to `object.ToString` that they turn into undefined.  So my question to you is are you sure you're code in your codebase matches the jsfiddle?

Also if you're using JSfiddle to make and test your code first, you might consider installing Brackets.io.  It has a nifty live update feature that makes web development easier for beginners and it opens up a preview on the browser.  I've noticed in the past that JSfiddle doesn't always operate the same as a browser.

Comment: I think you mean `object.toString()`. You'll get `undefined` for `object.ToString` because `.ToString` is the wrong name for that method. JavaScript is case-sensitive

Comment: Well that explains what I was seeing then